# My icloud account was hacked, I changed the password, what else should I do?

Tags: icloud, security

This morning I woke up just to find several messages sent to a Chinese number in my imessage app. I also found an email in my mail by Apple saying that someone had log in with my credential on an iMac (I don't own that).

Apple did good and blocked my account and asked me to change my password and I did so. The questions I have now are the following:

- Should I be worried? I have several password stored in my icloud keychain, are all of them compromised now? Should I change them all one by one? Are credit card details also compromised?

Comment: If you used that password elsewhere, change it there too

Comment: Also: enable 2fa!

Comment: Sadly I can´t do so since I travel a lot and constantly change my sim card so I am using several different phone numbers :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if they activated "Keychain" using another device you should change your passwords.

Keep in mind that activating "Keychain" in the iCloud preferences should require you to confirm the device using another device.

Please check to see how your account's authentication is currently set up (e.g. log out of your Apple ID on your Mac (iCloud), turn on iCloud using your Apple ID and try to activate "Keychain". Now your Mac should prompt you to activate Keychain using on of your other devices.